# View Desktop of all currently logged in Users on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, kvm-virtualization, desktop

We're running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise in a small research project at home. We need multiple users running Software in the background. For Monitoring purposes I'd like to have the ability to show/monitor all running sessions and what the Sofware is doing.

This is for a show we'd like to attend. We would setup a plasma there and all four desktops should be shown on the plasma, while the software controls the cursor and does something.

How can this be achieved most easily?

The Server is virtualized under Debian as a KVM virtual machine using virt-manager.

Comment: Are you wanting to monitor Remote Desktop sessions on a RDS host, or some other kind of session?

Comment: It's about viewing the Remote Desktop Sessions, not other sessions. We automated Mouse movement and want to show our "virtual users" working in ... like 4in1 on a Plasma :)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 main ways:

- From the PC having the plasma, open 4 RDP connection using a different windows account each time. Then play with resolution to get all 4 RDP on same big screen
- Connect from 4 laptop to the server using RDP. Then use another software (dameware, teamviewer, logmein..) to make one connection to each 4 sessions at same time on screen.

Pros/cons:

- First solution is much more elegant. Need to install the Remote desktop Role on server, and create 4 accounts. RDP License is running in grace period for 120 days if you can't provide RDP cal license.
- Second solution looks like **shame**, but it allows your friend to stay in backstage, and do manipulations in each session while your are speaking. Like repairing or spawing the job if it fails during the demo.

The goal is not to make something for production, but just working during a demo.